# All USB devices go to sleep in idle mode on Windows 7

Tags: windows, usb, sleep, power-management

A strange thing happened after a few updates to the system:

- Intel rapid storage
- SSD firmware update
- Intel Ethernet adapter update
- GPU Intel update

When the computer turns off the screen (after five minutes), an unknown time later, all the USB devices stop working.

- Sound card
- Mouse
- Keybord
- etc.

I can't turn them back on, so I can't wake up the screen or do anything except turn the computer off and back on.

I checked my power save profile and all is OK there. I changed in [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager), the `Allow USB to sleep` in all the hubs.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at Control Panel > Power Options, then go to Change Power Settings > Change Advanced Power Settings > Usb Settings > Usb Selective Suspend Settings, and set it to Disabled? That looks like another setting that could allow the computer to suspend usb devices.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately power settings can be found in different locations. In addition to the answer of William Saunders I would check the BIOS of your machine and the device management options of your USB components. Sometimes the device settings are power-saving related. I noticed that with USB expansion card for PCI and PCI Express.