# How to stop USB devices from disconnecting on sleep?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, sleep, dell-precision

I have a Dell Precision 5520 (laptop) and as it's my only Windows PC I'm unable to see if it's a Dell or Windows problem.

I use various types of hardware such as CAN bus analyzers, MCU programmers and various others which each has their own software.

The problem I have is that if the PC sleeps, upon wake up the software sees the hardware as disconnected. Some software crashes and some I have to reconfigure or mess around to get it to work again.

Is there a way I can get the PC to sleep without disconnecting USB devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you can try this:

Refer to the following steps.

1. Open `Control panel`, and click `view by` to select `small icons`
2. Click `Power Options`
3. Find the current plans (in my PC is `Balanced`)
4. Click `Change plan settings`
5. Click `Change advanced power settings` in the new Window
6. In the new Window, click Change settings that are current unavailable
7. Then find `USB settings` -> `USB selective suspend settings`
8. **Disable** it

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Start the `Device Manager` `(devmgmt.msc)` in `System Control`.

Most USB devices have configurable energy settings. You can change them to disallow energy saving in sleep mode.

[image]

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/514250/all-usb-devices-go-to-sleep-in-idle-mode-on-windows-7?rq=1) might also be relevant.

Comment: USB devices don't disconnect when put into "sleep" mode, aka USB SUSPEND. They disconnect when internal hubs are turned OFF. Originally the USB tree was not supposed to turn power off ever, but in laptop world even a small drain would cause user experience problem, so laptops invented this extra power state, "D3(cold)". That's where the disconnect happens. The above solution might solve the problem, but the marketing image of "power savvy laptop" might silently override this function.

Answer (score 3):

OOOO's answer is great but in some circumstances Windows might hide the `Change settings that are current unavailable` option. It is possible to change the `USB selective suspend settings` via the command line:

1. Enable the power plan you wish to change
2. Open `cmd`
3. To disable:

```dos
REM (On battery: Disabled)
powercfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT 2a737441-1930-4402-8d77-b2bebba308a3 48e6b7a6-50f5-4782-a5d4-53bb8f07e226 0
REM (Plugged in: Disabled)
powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT 2a737441-1930-4402-8d77-b2bebba308a3 48e6b7a6-50f5-4782-a5d4-53bb8f07e226 0
```

4. To re-enable:

```dos
REM  (On battery: Enabled) - Default
powercfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT 2a737441-1930-4402-8d77-b2bebba308a3 48e6b7a6-50f5-4782-a5d4-53bb8f07e226 1
REM (Plugged in: Enabled) - Default
powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT 2a737441-1930-4402-8d77-b2bebba308a3 48e6b7a6-50f5-4782-a5d4-53bb8f07e226 1
```

Adapted from: [How to Turn On or Off USB Selective Suspend in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/73187-turn-off-usb-selective-suspend-windows-10-a.html)

Note: The GUIDs are well known GUIDs defined by Windows:

```
> powercfg -list
> powercfg -query <your_power_plan_GUID>

[...]
  Subgroup GUID: 2a737441-1930-4402-8d77-b2bebba308a3  (USB settings)
    Power Setting GUID: 48e6b7a6-50f5-4782-a5d4-53bb8f07e226  (USB selective suspend setting)
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Disabled
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Enabled
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers aren't bad, but in my experience the rabbit hole can go *much* more deeper:

- first, every recent laptop supports modern standby, and that can [definitively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/prepare-hardware-for-modern-standby) influence USB power states
- secondly, Windows 10 has this [new option](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/145957-how-turn-off-stop-devices-when-screen-off-windows-10-a.html) where it explicitly turns off USB devices on sleep
- thirdly each individual [device](https://web.archive.org/web/20170717152747/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn707976(v=vs.85).aspx#configure_selective_suspend_for_usbser.sys) [driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/winusb-power-management) may have its specific preferences (even though you'd certainly expect them to be appropriate OOTB for whatever their use case is)
- and if we continue to dig further, there are then all the [different](https://superuser.com/questions/749982/prevent-windows-7-from-enabling-power-saving-on-usb-3-0-hub) [kinds](https://web.archive.org/web/20140415233025/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usbcoreblog/archive/2013/11/15/usb-2-0-lpm.aspx) of [hidden](https://github.com/mattifestation/MSFTTraceMessageFormat/blob/master/usbhub3.tmf) [knobs](https://forum.corsair.com/forums/topic/95066-windows-81-temporary-workaround/) that piled up during the years within the drivers of the OS's USB stack
- which [some](https://communityforums.atmeta.com/t5/Get-Help/Fix-for-Sensor-Disconnection-Issue/td-p/538625/page/29#M53380) [suggest](https://rog-forum.asus.com/t5/x99/disconnecting-reconnecting-usb-ports/td-p/729274#M31204) that you could look into [replacing](https://winraid.level1techs.com/t/outdated-usb-3-0-3-1-drivers-original-and-modded/30871) altogether
- last but not least, there are the [bios](https://9m2tpt.blogspot.com/2016/05/pipo-x9s-double-drivers-dump.html), [firmware](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/100-series-chipset-spec-update.pdf) and [hardware](https://www.anandtech.com/show/16554/amd-set-to-roll-out-agesa-firmware-usb-fix-for-ryzen-coming-april) levels
- mindful most of them just eventually set some USB Controller register, you could try to [edit them directly](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technical-specifications/extensible-host-controler-interface-usb-xhci.pdf#page=415) with tools such as RWEverything